# MUI material autocomplete onBlur not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

In material autocomplete onFocus is working but onBlur parameter is not working. Can anyone suggest why? and what's the correct solution to implement it.

```js
<Autocomplete
        onBlur={() => {
          console.log("false")
        }}
        onFocus={() => {
          console.log("true")
        }}
        multiple
        id="combo-box-demo"
        options={props.category}
        style={{ margin: '10px', width: '300px' }}
        size='small'
        value={assign}
        getOptionLabel={(option) => option.category}
        onChange={(event, newValue) => setAssign(newValue)}
        filterSelectedOptions
        renderInput={(params) => (
          <TextField
            {...params}
            label="Category"
            placeholder="Select Category"
            size='small'
          />
        )}
      />
```

I tried setting states and even logging the event handler response, it didn't worked.

Comment: Have you clicked outside of autocomplete component ?

Comment: If you want the onblur to work on the input you might need to add it to the TextField

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your code is fully worked. Checkout the [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/polished-cloud-enqhjt?file=/demo.js). Probably the mistake is somewhere else

Comment: That sandbox example is not relevant. He is using multiline Autocomplete, you are referring to single select autocomplete. Remove options in multi autocomplete does not trigger onBlur when removing selected options by click